# Flex box in flex box, and positioning not works. (Flexbox in flexbox)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**UPDATE**

For those, whom not like the inline CSS, and want classes, here are another [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8pe0j00/) with classes and with stylesheet.

**UPDATE END**

I want to make a product page. It will have three columns.
The first is the picture, second is some specification, third is the "into basket". All of the columns content is dynamic, so I'll never know, what is the taller, and what is the size of that.

What I try to do is:

- Be all the three column heights as the height of the tallest column.
- In the second column, I need the specification of the product (now lorem ipsum) on the top of the box, and some information at the bottom of the box. (The 123456).

So, I made the three columns with flexbox `technique` and it works, as I expected. (Because of this will be responsive, later I need to change the orders of the 3 columns on specified width, but it is not relevant now).

Ok, I thought, if I put another `flex` div into the second column, but now with column mode, it will does the job.

But not. I do not understand, why the second columns second flex box height is not tall as the column, (I sad `strech`, and `justify-content: space-between`)

I should do it for the 3rd column too.

I used inline stylesheet, maybe it is readable.

It works only in FF, and IE, but not in Opera and Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flex teszt</title>
        <style>
            p {margin-bottom: 17px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                    <!-- Big and first flex container -->
        <div style="width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid #000; box-sizing: border-box;">
            <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap; justify-content: space-between ; flex-direction: row; align-items: stretch; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid #f00">
                <div style="width: 32%; box-sizing: border-box; order: 1; border: 1px solid #f00;">
                    <img src="http://vaso.hu/venus.jpg" style="width: 100%;" alt="">
                </div>

                <div style="width: 32%; box-sizing: border-box; order: 2; border: 1px solid #0f0; box-sizing: border-box;">
                    <div style="height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; align-items: stretch; justify-content: space-between;  width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
                        <div style="border: 1px solid #00f; width: 100%; order: 1" >
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                        </div>
                        <div style="border: 1px solid #00f; width: 100%; aling-self: flex-end; box-sizing: border-box; display: block; order: 2">123456</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="width: 32%; box-sizing: border-box; order: 3; border: 1px solid #f0f; box-sizing: border-box;">
                    789
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /big and first flex container -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the **[jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pgn9756z/1/)** link.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: I would like to help you but I can't read your code as its currently hard to see what style apply's to what markup(html), since you don't use any classes. Could you post your code with a CSS stylesheet?

Comment: I've updated my question, so at the top of the question, there are another jsFiddle link, there are classes, no inline styles.

Comment: Thank you for the downvote! So nice, without any explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Remove `height: 100%;` from `.secondCol .innerFlex`, its container has no height set so the browser does not know how high 100% should be
- Add  `display: flex;` `.secondCol` this will allow `.innerFlex` to fill its available height

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #f00
}
.firstCol {
  width: 32%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  order: 1;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
.secondCol {
  display: flex; /*Add this*/
  width: 32%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  order: 2;
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.secondCol .innerFlex {
  /*height: 100%; Remove this*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.secondCol .innerFlex .firstItem {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  width: 100%;
  order: 1
}
.secondCol .innerFlex .secondItem {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  width: 100%;
  aling-self: flex-end;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  order: 2
}
.thirdCol {
  width: 32%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  order: 3;
  border: 1px solid #f0f;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flexContainer">
    <div class="firstCol">
      <img src="http://vaso.hu/venus.jpg" style="width: 100%;" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="secondCol">
      <div class="innerFlex">
        <div class="firstItem">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </div>
        <div class="secondItem">123456</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="thirdCol">
      789
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /big and first flex container -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. +1, because it definietly works at here. Now I try to implement it in my environment, and if it works, I will accept. If not, I come back to ask. Thanks again.

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you very much again. I sucked with it for two and half a day.

Comment: There is one more quick question. In `secondItem`, `123456` how can be aligned to bottom? Tried `align-self: flex-end` but it does not helped.

Comment: Ah yes, there is a small typo `aling-self: flex-end;`, fixing that should do the trick.